# Proper way to execute a query in a backing bean and update a table in ADF

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have a search button that should execute a backing bean method, execute a query and then refresh the table.  I'm changing the bind parameters of the query in the process.  What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to follow MVC model. To do that just use this algorithm:

Create implementation of your viewobject interface. Here you can define method with parameters that you will pass to the query. To do that just go to the Viewobject definition - "Java tab" - "Java classes" edit and check "Generate View Object class: YourViewObjectViewImpl" and "Include bind variable accessors", then press ok button. Find out class YourViewObjectViewImpl.java and implement method with parameter you need.
    For example you need 2 parameters to refresh your VO:

```
public class YourViewObjectViewImpl extends ViewObjectImpl {

    // Generated method
    public void setA(Long value) {
        setNamedWhereClauseParam(value);
    }

    // Generated method
    public void setB(Long value) {
        setNamedWhereClauseParam(value);
    }

    // Your custom method
    public void refreshQuery(long a, long b) {
        this.clearCache();
        setA(a);
        setB(b);
        this.executeQuery();
    }
}
```

Now you need to make this method visible for ViewController. In java tab from your ViewObject definition press edit on "Client interface" and move in the shuttle refreshQuery method to the right side. Press OK. Now Jdev generates two classes wich will gelp you to make your method visible in ViewController project.

Next step is to define your refreshQuery in page definition bindings. 
Go to the page definition and press + button on Bindings panel. Select methodAction from the list. Select ViewObject from AppModuleDataControl and select refreshQuery method in the Operation combobox. In the table with parameters you can define values using expression language. For example #{viewScope.myBean.a} and #{viewScope.myBean.b} Press ok.

Now you are able to execute this method from bean for example:

```
public class MyBean {
    public Long a = 0;
    public Long b = 0;

    public void refresh() {
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        BindingContext bc = BindingContext.getCurrent();
        DCBindingContainer dcbc = (DCBindingContainer)bc.getCurrentBindingsEntry();
        dcbc.getOperationBinding("refreshQuery");
        dcbc.execute();
    }    
}
```